# Google Chrome: current address outside of omnibox

Tags: google-chrome

Something broke in my chrome install and now my current url is outside to the left of my omnibox:

[image: Picture here]

I can even click it as a button and it brings me to that page, also it will always stay blank, even when typing in it.

Is there a way to reset the layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you accidentally enabled a flag which does that or maybe it got enabled on the dev channel.

Copy the following into the address bar and press `Enter`:

```
chrome://flags/#origin-chip
```

Find the `Enable origin chip` flag and disable it from the dropdown.

Click `Relaunch Now` at the bottom.

Comment: I highly doubt someone would accidentally enable that flag. This coincides with me [definitely NOT enabling it 4 days later](http://superuser.com/questions/739846/how-can-i-re-enable-the-path-in-chromes-address-bar), so it may be a Chrome update.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Hehe. I guess, I forgot to consider the fact that you guys might be on the dev channel, which is the only other likely explanation because it certainly didn't enable itself on the stable channel.

Comment: I'm not on the dev channel actually. Chrome definitely updated itself - the scrollbars got their arrows back.

Comment: There is no longer an "origin chip" in Chrome flags to configure.

Comment: @janaspage i would think that the feature has been removed completely. do you still get the issue similar to OP?

Comment: @Cybertox: I actually came here looking for a way to force Chrome to display the `http://`/`https://` protocol of URLs in the omnibar. :(