# How can I re-enable the path in Chrome's address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

In its latest update today, Version 34.0.1847.116 m (April 9, 2014), Google Chrome removed the full URL from the address bar. This is super super annoying to developers who want to be able to see the path and parameters. Instead, Chrome only displays the domain, presumably to make some lame URL hacking exploits (http://malwa.re/www.yourbank.com) impossible to pull off.

I know the URL is visible if I press Ctrl+L, but that's inconvenient. How can the old style full URL be brought back in the address bar / omnibox?

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure there isn't an option or an extension that already exists before asking this question?

Comment: @Ramhound: yes, I have. I haven't installed anything new. Chrome crashed, then when it restarted - boom this annoying change. I hadn't messed with `chrome://flags` either. I assume there was an update, though I don't have a precise recollection of the version number prior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An an [earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/737979/google-chrome-current-address-outside-of-omnibox) pointed out, you need to go to

chrome://flags/#origin-chip <sup>(sorry, SuperUser won't let me hyperlink this)</sup>

And disable all the Origin chip stuff.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be there anymore (Chrome 45)