# Show http:// again in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When you browse to a non-https site, the http:// portion of the URL is hidden. Example:

[image]

However, on https pages it will automatically prepend the https://, even if you don't include it (which is a good thing). Example:

[image]

Is it possible to force the http:// to show, and automatically prepend it to the beginning of a URL if it's missing?

Comment: "WontFix" @ https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41467

Comment: Perhaps the following link that I found will help you:

http://superuser.com/questions/737979/google-chrome-current-address-outside-of-omnibox

Comment: @gp443 That question is different than what I'm asking

Comment: The only solution right now would be to [fix it yourself][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988588/recompiling-a-part-of-google-chrome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Chrome 83 there is an `omnibox-context-menu-show-full-urls` flag that enables showing full URLs in the omnibox.

```
chrome://flags/#omnibox-context-menu-show-full-urls
```

1. Copy and paste the URL.
2. Select *Enabled*.
3. Relaunch the browser.

Now you'll see the full URL in the address bar:

[image: Chrome omnibox]

---

*For Chrome 82 and older:*

The easiest solution now is to just to **download the [Suspicious Site Reporter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/suspicious-site-reporter/jknemblkbdhdcpllfgbfekkdciegfboi) extension** from the Chrome Store. And that's it.

As we can see in the source code, the protocol will not get hidden if this extension is installed:

[image: Chromium source code]
[image: Chromium source code]

---

Previously, setting the `omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-trivial-subdomains` flag was the easiest way to show the "https://www." back again, but it has been removed as of Chrome 76.

[image: chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-trivial-subdomains]

```
chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-trivial-subdomains
```

Comment: Thanks, I installed it and from inspecting its background page for ~20 minutes while browsing it doesn't appear to make any network requests (unless you click it and submit a report), so I guess this is a fine workaround. Out of curiosity, how did you come across this solution? From your screenshot it looks like you ctrl+f'd for that exact variable name

Comment: I was browsing the buganizer looking for possible solutions and came across [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883038#c198) and [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883038#c128) comment.
Before I also tried asking if it was possible to renew the flag (it's just a matter of changing one number), but I didn't get any response...

Comment: NOTE, in addition to enabling the flag/experiment I had to right click in the URL bar and select "Always Show Full URLs"

Comment: That flag seems to be gone now (at least in my Chrome). Looks like "Always Show Full URLs" is all that's required now.

Answer (score 10):

Just for future reference, in the current chromium version you need to disable both of the following flags in order to get the full URL:

```
chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme

chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-trivial-subdomains
```

Edit: See above answer

Comment: It seems these flags disappeared with Chrome 79.

Answer (score 6):

You can navigate to `chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme-and-subdomains` and disable **Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL Scheme and Trivial Subdomains**.

Comment: I tried that but I still don't see the http when I browse to http.badssl.com (even explicitly typing in http://). Does this flag still work?

Comment: At the moment it seems to only show `https://` again. `http://` is still hidden.

Comment: chrome://flags/#omnibox-context-menu-show-full-urls and then right click location bar and select always show full urls is the only thing that works right now.

Answer (score 3):

As a work around, you can drag the icon in the left side of the url (the i with a circle around it for an http address or the lock symbol for an https address) into the url box and drop it. That will show "http://" again as part of the address.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome version 103, you can right-click the address bar (omnibox) and check the "Always show full URLs" option.