# Show http schema in Omnibox from Chrome 80

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

I updated to Chrome v80 today and the Chrome flags to see http schema in omnibox seem to be gone now.

Earlier, this method described in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1408366/398328) used to work , but it doesn't anymore.

Any alternative solutions.

Comment: Bump...........

Comment: I end up downgrading the Chrome. I'm hoping G$$gle change their mind or I find a better replacement of Chrome in future. Meanwhile v77 is the recommended version from me (It's before they remove "Close other tabs"). If anybody need link for it, just ping me.